# heroku times out every time on post request

Tags: node.js, heroku

My app works fine locally and I have a much more complicated app running on heroku. But I consistently get a 503 / H12 timeout when it tries to run a POST request. It takes two seconds locally. Any ideas?

The post route in question (uses a node.js sdk for aylien nlp api):

```
app.post('/apiRequest', (req, res) => {
    const reqUrl = req.body.url;

    aylienApi.combined({
        'url': reqUrl,
        'endpoint': ['language', 'sentiment', 'summarize'] 
    }, function(error, result) {
        if (error === null){
            res.send(result.results)
        }
    })
})
```

The async POST request:

```
const postData = async (url = '', data = {}) => {
    const res = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })

    try {
        const articleData = await res.json();
        return articleData;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
    }
}
```

I've read on the heroku documentation that it can be caused by large bits of data, but I'm only grabbing a small amount of JSON and send a url.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had not uploaded by .env file with the api keys etc, as it was still in the gitignore file.

Silly me. But turns out the Aylien nlp api doesn't warn you if the key isn't set.